# Graphical imperfections when plotting a fourier series

Tags: plotting, graphics

When running the following I get the plot below. I'm a beginner, can anyone suggest why we see those graphical imperfections in the plot?

```
ClearAll[P];
F[x_]:=Piecewise[{{1,Mod[x,2Pi]<Pi},{0,Mod[x,2Pi]>Pi}}];
FourierSeries[F[x],x,100];
Plot[%,{x,0,4Pi}]
```

[image: Fourier Series of a rectangular signal]

Comment: You need to use more `PlotPoints`.

Comment: @Roman: Thanks, it worked fine with PlotPoints->1000.

Comment: Hi Ang, welcome to Mma.SE. Start by **taking the [tour] now** and learning about [asking](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O) and what's [on-topic](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O). Always [edit] if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context. Thanks for your minimal working example and your code in [formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX). By doing all this you help us to help you and likely you will inspire great answers. The site depends on participation, as you receive **give back:** vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer, but I think you were too hasty doing that. While *accepting* is one of the [things to do after your question is answered](https://wolfr.am/v57DB3p4), we recommend that users should **test answers before [voting](https://wolfr.am/v57ItzJq)** and **wait 24 hours before [accepting](https://wolfr.am/v57LwTXD)** the best one. That allows people in all timezones to answer your question and an opportunity for other users to point alternatives, caveats or limitations of the available answers.

Comment: What are the graphical imperfections (probably my eyes are missing something)?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: please compare the question picture with the answer picture.

Comment: They look quite similar to me. I guess the concern is that some of the wiggles are under-sampled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Answer

As pointed out by @Roman, you should increase the default value for [`PlotPoints`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotPoints.html). You should also increase the value of [`MaxRecursion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxRecursion.html). Play and find a compromise between `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion`. By increasing these values you will make computation much slower and the plot figure much heavier (if in vector form).

I recommend at least 4 points per period at your highest frequency and a recursion of at least 3.

You can see that the points that come from the recursion are cleverly placed where needed to create a smoother curve, but the ones from plot points are regularly spaced, so irregular curves benefit more from a larger `MaxRecursion`.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Points in the [`Mesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mesh.html) grow very fast with the value of `MaxRecursion`.

### Explanation

From the documentation for [`Plot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html), which should be the first thing to read if you are experiencing a problem,

> Plot initially evaluates $f$ at a number of equally spaced sample points
>   specified by [`PlotPoints`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotPoints.html). Then it uses an adaptive algorithm to choose
>   additional sample points, subdividing a given interval at most
>   [`MaxRecursion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxRecursion.html) times.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Example

```
ClearAll[P];
F[x_] := Piecewise[{{1, Mod[x, 2 Pi] < Pi}, {0, Mod[x, 2 Pi] > Pi}}];
Plot[
 Evaluate[FourierSeries[F[x], x, 100]]
 , {x, 0, 4 Pi}
 , PlotPoints -> 800
 , MaxRecursion -> 4
 , PlotTheme -> "Scientific"
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]